# Logarithmic Scaling of Y2 axis while keeping Y1 axis linear in dygraphs

Tags: dygraphs

I have two axes Y and Y2 used for plotting a dygraph. The values in y2 axes varies exponentially and labels thus clutters. I would like to scale this axis while keeping y axes linear.
I have already tried logcale : true option but was of no help.
Please help, if this option is supported in dygraph.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It might be an indicator about the design of your graph.  That said have you looked at this?

> Gridlines and axis labels make charts easier to understand. They give
>   the lines a clear scale. Unless you tell it otherwise, dygraphs will
>   choose a y-axis and set of gridlines which include all of your data.
>
> If you have many series with different scales, this will compress the
>   variation in all but the largest one. Standard ways to deal with this
>   include secondary y-axes and log scales.
>
> If neither of these is to your liking, you can manually rescale your
>   series and undo that scaling for the hover values. This demo shows how
>   to do it.
>
> http://dygraphs.com/preview/tests/multi-scale.html

Answer (score 0):

Dygraphs doesn't currently support log scale per axis. We' love to do it, but it will take some time. See https://code.google.com/p/dygraphs/issues/detail?id=126 to follow progress against it.